# Can I use "contend" without a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, meaning-in-context, legalese

> On the one hand, recent advances in the power of computers have been decried as the nemesis of whatever vestiges of our privacy still survive. On the other, the Internet is acclaimed as a Utopia. When **clichés contend**, it is imprudent to expect sensible resolutions of the problems they embody, but between these two exaggerated claims, something resembling the truth probably resides.

There's no clause after contend here, so [definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contend?q=contend) must be the only choice. Yet no preposition exists after **contend** here, so it exceeds the dictionary? Is this an appropriate use of "contend"? Does "contend" always need a preposition?

Source: P136, Law, Raymond Wacks

Comment: To contend: (Intr.)
To strive in controversy or debate; dispute. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Contend

Comment: *contend:* clash, conflict, disagree, be at loggerheads with, oppose, repugn

Comment: There *is* a clause after "contend" there.

Comment: @Robusto: Please explain. Where?

Comment: Actually, there are three clauses after *contend*, but directly after it comes the main clause of the sentence, beginning "it is imprudent . . ." The first clause of the sentence ("When clichés contend") may be viewed as subordinate to that one.

Comment: I would say the writer just used *when clichés contend* because he wanted to avoid the somewhat clichéed usage ***mixed metaphor***. But it strikes me as clumsy phrasing.

Comment: If you substitute 'conflict' then it makes better sense.

Comment: I've edited the question with the intent of resolving the close reason. Hopefully this will make the question more appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implied clause that provides the missing "with":

> When clichés contend [with each other], it is imprudent to expect sensible resolutions of the problems they embody, but between these two exaggerated claims, something resembling the truth probably resides.

This implied clause is fairly common when using the word "contend":

> When two heavyweight champions contend, the match is always entertaining!

Answer (score -2):

I'd guess they've used the wrong word by accident. If the sentence read 'When cliches abound' instead, it makes sense.

Comment: No, it's the cliché "nemesis of privacy" contending with the cliché "acclaimed as Utopia".